# Why does this JavaFX/Swing code not show on some computers?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, javafx, jar

When the following code is compiled into an executable JAR, it produces varying results.

On half of the computers we tested, the Java FX Window has to be moved before the content (the swing node) displays as it should. On the other half, it displays content without manipulation of the window. All computers were Windows based (some W10, some W7).

The JRE (1.8.0_121) is packaged into the program, and a batch file points the JAR to that JRE.

```
HistoryWindow(Task task, Scene scene) {
    history = task.getHistoryItems();
    String text = "";
    t = task;
    sc = scene;

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(new Dimension(1600,850));
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,0,20));
    panel.addMouseListener(this);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    pane = new ScrollPane();
    SwingNode swingN = new SwingNode();


    initAndSetPanel();//Placeholder for the setup of the JPanel added to the scrollPane

    scrollPane.revalidate();

    createSwingContent(swingN);
    pane.setContent(swingN);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 400, 850));
    mystage = stage;
    stage.setTitle("History window");
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stage.initOwner(
            (scene.getWindow()));
    //stage.show();
    stage.showAndWait()
    /* Same result as above
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stage.showAndWait();
        }
    });*/

}
```

The createSwingNode(swingNode) method creates the swing node using SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

```
private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swingNode.setContent(scrollPane);
            }
        });
    }
```

The code always runs up to the stage.showAndWait() (verified through print statements), and I'm unsure what's causing the discrepancy in results. Help would be much appreciated.

In case the Jpanel setup is causing the discrepancy, here's the code for it (can be inserted at placeholder method). Also, don't judge me for this code because I didn't write it :)

```
for(HistoryItem his : history){
            Date day = his.getDate();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy | hh:mm aa");
            text = sdf.format(day);

            text = text + " | " + his.getText();

            String addText = "";

            try{
                NameChange name = (NameChange)his;
                addText = "Changed name from " + name.getOldName() + " to " + name.getNewName();
            }catch(Exception e){}

            try{
                Comment com = (Comment)his;
                addText = com.getComment();
                commented = true;
            }catch(Exception e){}

            try{
                PriorityChange pri = (PriorityChange)his;
                String priOld = "";
                String priNew = "";

                switch(pri.getOldStatus()) {
                case 0: priOld = "inactive";break;
                case 1: priOld = "eventual";break;
                case 2: priOld = "current";break;
                case 3: priOld = "urgent";break;
                case 4: priOld = "completed";break; 
                }

                switch(pri.getNewStatus()) {
                case 0: priNew = "inactive";break;
                case 1: priNew = "eventual";break;
                case 2: priNew = "current";break;
                case 3: priNew = "urgent";break;
                case 4: priNew = "completed";break;
                }

                addText = "Changed priority from " + priOld + " to " + priNew;
            }catch(Exception e){}

            changeType = new JLabel(text);
            changeText = new JLabel(addText);

            holder = new JPanel();
            if(commented) {
                holder.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        in = true;
                        out = false;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        in = false;
                        out = true;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        /*JPanel a = (JPanel)e.getSource();
                        JLabel b = (JLabel)a.getComponent(1);
                        String withdraw = b.getText();
                        for(HistoryItem hist: history) {
                            try {
                                Comment comm = (Comment)hist;
                                if(comm.getComment().equals(withdraw))
                                    System.out.println("alsjdlkajsd");
                                    new FXCommentWindow(task, stage);
                                    System.out.println("Something happened");
                            } catch(Exception ex){}
                        }*/
                        if(firstClick == 0 || System.currentTimeMillis()/100 - firstClick > 4 && in) {
                            firstClick = System.currentTimeMillis()/100;
                            //System.out.println("First click: "+firstClick);
                        }
                        else if(System.currentTimeMillis()/100 - firstClick <= 4 && in) {
                            //System.out.println("First try?");
                            firstClick = 0;
                            JPanel a = (JPanel)e.getSource();
                            JLabel b = (JLabel)a.getComponent(1);
                            String withdraw = b.getText();
                            //System.out.println(withdraw);
                            for(HistoryItem hist: history) {
                                try {
                                    Comment comm = (Comment)hist;
                                    if(comm.getComment().equals(withdraw)) {
                                        clickCounter++;
                                        if ((clickCounter % 2) != 0) {
                                            //Ensures window is only opened once
                                            System.out.println("alsjdlkajsd");
                                            //Must run on new thread
                                            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    new FXCommentWindow(task,comm, stage);
                                                    System.out.println("fall through");
                                                    //updateAlt();
                                                    refresh(t,sc);
                                                }
                                            });
                                            //System.out.println("fall through");
                                        }
                                    }


                                } catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
                });
                commented = false;
            }
            holder.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,0,10));
            holder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            holder.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10,100));

            holder.add(changeType);
            holder.add(changeText);
            panel.add(holder);

        }
```

Comment: What thread is `HistoryWindow(...)` (btw, please use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)) called on? You have some threading anomalies here, because you are clearly creating some swing content (`panel = new JPanel()`, `scrollPane = new JScrollPane()`, etc) on the same thread as you are creating some JavaFX content (`stage = new Stage()`, etc). So it seems at least likely that you are violating the threading rules of one or other of the toolkits.

Comment: @James_D HistoryWindow is currently called from an FX thread. Should all FX action be wrapped in a Platform.runLater, and should HistoryWindow be called using SwingUtilities.invokeLater?

Comment: If `HistoryWindow` is already being executed on the FX application thread, then `Platform.runLater(...)` would be redundant. But that means you are creating the `JPanel` and `JScrollPane` on the FX Application Thread, and those really should be created on the AWT Event Dispatch thread (EDT). So I would move the creation and configuration of the `JPanel` and `JScrollPane` to the `createSwingContent` method, inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)`, so that it is executed on the EDT. Similarly your `initAndSetPanel` method should be on the EDT too.

Comment: Probably your best bet, tbh, is to go through an exercise in cleaning the code up. Simplifying it may be the best way to figure out where things are going wrong. This code looks like you should be able to get away with it, threading-wise (because the components accessed on the "wrong" thread are only accessed there before they are displayed), but any time you're accessing UI components on multiple threads (as you must be with `panel` and `scrollPane`), it gets hard to figure out if it's correct.

Comment: @James_D I wrapped all of the Swing stuff in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` and the issue just became weirder.
Now If I repeatedly open and close the HistoryWindow, sometimes it will display the content, and sometimes it still won't without moving the window.
Why does it display fine sometimes, but require the window to be moved other times?